# Tasselled Cap Transformation on MODIS in GRASS

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, modis

How do I perform a Tasselled Cap Transformation on MODIS, in GRASS?

I've found this

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/19063909/

but I don't know if this has been tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by WhiteboxDev's comment I have added MODIS support to [i.tasscap](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/i.tasscap.html) in revision [62197](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/62197). It is yet untested, please try it and report if all works fine.

In order to obtain this improvement, you need to either install/update GRASS GIS 7.1 or even simply grab the updated i.tasscap (which is a Python script [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/trunk/scripts/i.tasscap/)).

Answer (score 2):

The GRASS program that you linked to was written by Markus Neteler and he's done an excellent job of documenting the code. It appears that the tool has been written with the Tasseled Cap transformation (TCT) coefficients that are specific to Landsat TM and ETM (Landsat 4, 5 and 7). He makes a note in the documentation about whether or not it would make sense to add the coefficients for MODIS data but they haven't been. In actuality the transform is just a linear weighted combination so as long as you have the transformation weight values for your specific sensor, by band number, you can carry out the transformation with a raster algebra type solution using the raster calculator in any GIS. In the case of the MODIS sensor the weights are given in Lobser and Cohen (2007) [MODIS tasselled cap: land cover characteristics expressed through transformed MODIS data](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01431160701253303?journalCode=tres20#.VC7V-yldU8w), International Journal of Remote Sensing, Volume 28, Issue 22. The coefficients are in Table 3 of the article.

[image]

To calculate the Brightness, Greenness and Wetness rasters (the outputs) you simply need to multiply each of the input bands (Red, NIR1, Blue, etc.) by their various weights and sum the products. As an example:

Brightness = 0.4395*R+0.5945*NIR1+0.2460*B+0.3918*G+0.3506*NIR2+0.2136*SWIR1+0.2678*SWIR2

Where R, NIR1, B, G, etc. are the pixel-by-pixel values contained within each of the corresponding band data. A careful read of the paper first is probably a good idea though!